# Get camera information from Win32 API in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, camera, usb

After [finding out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151658/how-to-read-devices-and-driver-versions) how to retrieve driver and device information from the Device Manager in Windows, I want to know how I can get the camera information on my computer. I am using C#.  I can't find a suitable class listed on MSDN:

[Computer System Hardware Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273.aspx)

As can be seen in this image, the camera is located under the image processing devices.

[image]

Is there any possibility to check if the camera is activated?

**EDIT:**
The device is deactivated:

[image]
[image]

What I want to know is the following: Can I check the device's status code (currently 22) or some other property to check if the device is activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now managed to check the camera activity by using the [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) framework. The solution can be found here: https://github.com/SeppPenner/CameraActivityChecker

Answer (score 0):

The below post focuses on detecting USB devices, but I think it's the direction that you need to go:

[USB Device Connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685615/usb-device-connected)

Write a function to query for the desired device and verify that it is connected.

Comment: Good luck!  Hope it is helpful.  I'm not certain what you mean by "activated", but if you mean "connected", then I think this could work for you.  There might also be additional class helper methods you can access to get more specific information about the device, but I am not certain.

Outside of 'hooking' an existing proc and reading activity in realtime, not sure how you would identify whether or not the camera is actively capturing an image.

Comment: Well, the code worked for getting the device information. Still I'm not sure how I can find out if the device changes its status. I updated my question regarding this ;)

Comment: By the way: I'm sorry for the german language in the pictures... :D

Comment: I think it's easier to try to make a capture with [emguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and if this fails, the camera is not connected.

Comment: Nice find! It's cross platform too- very cool.  You should type up an answer so I can upvote.

Comment: Hi [Robert Hartshorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5302038/robert-hartshorn), I've put an answer below ;) My computer had hardware problems in the last weeks, that's why the reply is so late actually :D